# Ethernet adapter not activated after moving Ubuntu Server 20.04.02 LTS to new hardware

Tags: ethernet

I have moved my Ubuntu Server installation to a new machine. Just took the boot disk and installed to the new Machine.

Everything works fine, except for Ethernet.

Of course the Ethernet adapter has a new Id:enp9s0 (from eth0). I have done many searches to find where to change the adapter name to enp9s0, but with diferrent and confusing answers.

As a stop gap measure I have created a Startup crontab job that does:
ip link set enp9s0 up
dhclient enp9s0

This solves my problem, but not very clean.

Which config file should I Change ?
Here is the only file in /etc/netplan:

```
network:

  ethernets:

    enp30s0:

        dhcp4: true

version: 2
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and I can write you an answer. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I added the only entry in /etc/netplan.

Comment: @heynnema will try first thing tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your /etc/netplan/ .yaml file should look like...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/filename.yaml` # use the correct filename

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

**Note**: You may need to create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

Comment: Works. Thanks!   Did run accross that file BUT  the following comments at the top of the file initially made me decide not to try it: # This file is generated from information provided by # the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.

Comment: @Plaverdiere I added Update #1 to my answer. You can add this file if you find that the .yaml file is being overwritten.